# OPENCV : count pixel from the left edge of the image

Tags: c++, opencv

i want to know how to make a loop to count image pixel start counting pixels from the left edge of the image

how to make this using c++ opencv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to build the loop yourself, it is all already done for you.

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("img.jpg");
std::cout << img.total() << std::endl;
```

The first line loads your image into the standard C++ OpenCV container `Mat`. 
The second line prints the number of elements in the underlaying array of the `Mat`, in case of an image, this is equal to the total number of pixels of that image.

If those constructs were new to you, you should start with reading [these](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/table_of_content_core/table_of_content_core.html) tutorials.

Comment: Thx,but i want to know how to make this "The horizontal position, counting pixels from the left edge of the image, of the center
of the smallest rectangular box that can be drawn with all "on" pixels inside the box."
Note:the box==image

Comment: @Darsh You asked the question wrong, then. But the answer here is quite simple,elegant and fully answers the question.